# how to debug crashlytics stack trace of my android app which have no mention of my class names

Tags: java, android, crashlytics-android

This is the stack trace i got from crashlytics regarding a crash in my android app. I Can't find  classes from my package in crashlytics stack trace. What could be the problem? I don't know from where to start debugging? It was only happening in OS 5.0.x.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
length=0; index=0
 Raw Text
android.util.ContainerHelpers.binarySearch (ContainerHelpers.java:28)
android.util.ArrayMap.indexOf (ArrayMap.java:96)
android.util.ArrayMap.indexOfKey (ArrayMap.java:342)
android.util.ArrayMap.remove (ArrayMap.java:589)
android.app.LoadedApk.removeContextRegistrations (LoadedApk.java:664)
android.app.ContextImpl.performFinalCleanup (ContextImpl.java:2387)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1532)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:189)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5530)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:950)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Comment: Better question to put whole log.

Comment: Sadly,that is all I got from crashlytics.